# how to write regular expression in C# to get only alphabets words

Tags: c#, regex, string

how to write regular expression in C# to get only alphabets words that is not concatenated with numbers,special characters.
I have following text "**About Time (2013) [1080p]**"  and want the output like **About Time**

This is what I have tried

```
string myString="About Time (2013) [1080p]";
Regex.Replace(myString, @"[^a-zA-Z]+", " ");
```

It's returning as like this **About Time p**

Comment: You'll find [DISTINGUISH TORRENT FILES (SERIES VS MOVIES)](https://regex101.com/r/yP4bY4/1) interesting

Comment: in that case you can check for alphabets adjoining to numbers and remove/exclude them as well

Comment: @Tushar , That's really good stuff.. Thanks,

Comment: Welcome @PraveenMP I guess that's what you're trying to do. Removing crap from filenames.

Comment: @Sayse I am replacing the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do without `Regex`

```
string myString = "About Time (2013) [1080p]";
var words = myString.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var alphaWords = string.Join(" ", words.Where(w => w.All(Char.IsLetter)));
```

What it does is

[1] Splits the string into words (separated by space)
[2] Takes only those words where all characters are letter
[3] Joins them back with space as separator

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

you can check the word bounderies with \b

```
\b[a-zA-Z]+\b
```

but this way you still find the words bewteen round brackets or square brackets

[example here](https://regex101.com/r/vB0xF0/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString="About Time (2013) [1080p]";
Regex.Replace(myString, @"\S*[^a-zA-Z\s]\S*", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string FilterTest(string input) => string
                      .Join(" ", (new Regex(@"[a-z]+",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                      .Matches(input)
                      .Cast<Match>().Select(e => e.Value));
```